# How to join matched strings based on ID in javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to get task names grouped based on the `id`. In the given example below:

There is an array with the name `array1`. There are multiple objects inside with id and task name as properties.

I have made a counter function inside to check for the count of each `id`.

So after this, I have made `map` function and inside that checking for the count of each id using `counter[item.id]`.

If the count is 1 then no problem but if the id has multiple counts then i need to group the string based on the id.

```js
var array1 = [
  {id:1, taskname: 'Task 1'},
  {id:1, taskname: 'Task 2'},
  {id:2, taskname: 'Task 3'},
  {id:1, taskname: 'Task 4'},
  {id:3, taskname: 'Task 5'},
  {id:2, taskname: 'Task 6'},
  {id:1, taskname: 'Task 7'},
]

  var counter = {};

  array1.forEach(function(obj) {
      var key = obj.id;
      counter[key] = (counter[key] || 0) + 1;
  });
  
  array1.map(item => {
  if(counter[item.id] === 1) {
    console.log('has only one task name');
  } else {
     console.log('Multiple: how to group the names here based on the id? ');
  }
  });
```

Here string needs to get joined as single string with comma separator and **expected output** is,

```
array2 = [
{id: 1, taskname: 'Task 1, Task 2, Task 4, Task 7'},
{id: 2, taskname: 'Task 3, Task 6' },
{id: 3, taskname: 'Task 5'}
]
```

How to achieve the above-expected result by grouping the task name as a single string with comma separator based on the `id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a reduce function to group the tasks based on id. Then iterate over keys to join the tasks to a string like so:

```js
var array1 = [
  {id:1, taskname: 'Task 1'},
  {id:1, taskname: 'Task 2'},
  {id:2, taskname: 'Task 3'},
  {id:1, taskname: 'Task 4'},
  {id:3, taskname: 'Task 5'},
  {id:2, taskname: 'Task 6'},
  {id:1, taskname: 'Task 7'},
]

var obj = array1.reduce((acc, currentTask)=>{
  if(!acc[currentTask.id]){
    acc[currentTask.id] = [currentTask.taskname];
  }else{
    acc[currentTask.id].push(currentTask.taskname);
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

var arr  = Object.keys(obj).map(key => ({id : Number(key), taskname: obj[key].join(',')}));

console.log(arr);
```

```css
array2 = [
{id: 1, taskname: 'Task 1, Task 2, Task 4, Task 7'},
{id: 2, taskname: 'Task 3, Task 6' },
{id: 3, taskname: 'Task 5'}
]
```

Comment: In my real application my id is not a number and it is encrypted id and i need to get it using like this ```currentTask.billrate.getUid()``` ..  And the value will be like ```1tKAicPCYfg6xB``` .. To be clear enough with question i have made id like this..

Comment: Fine.. i will edit and keep the original answer as is.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than counting up the number of occurrences, when encountering an id, push the taskname string to an array in the accumulator for that ID. Then, at the end, `.map` and join every array by commas:

```js
var array1 = [
  {id:1, taskname: 'Task 1'},
  {id:1, taskname: 'Task 2'},
  {id:2, taskname: 'Task 3'},
  {id:1, taskname: 'Task 4'},
  {id:3, taskname: 'Task 5'},
  {id:2, taskname: 'Task 6'},
  {id:1, taskname: 'Task 7'},
];

const groupedInitial = array1.reduce((a, { id, taskname }) => {
  if (!a[id]) {
    a[id] = { id, taskname: [] };
  }
  a[id].taskname.push(taskname);
  return a;
}, {});
const output = Object.values(groupedInitial).map(
  ({ id, taskname }) => ({ id, taskname: taskname.join(', ') })
);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce the array and find the object with same `id`, then update or push a new object to the result set.

```js
var array = [{ id: 1, taskname: 'Task 1' }, { id: 1, taskname: 'Task 2' }, { id: 2, taskname: 'Task 3' }, { id: 1, taskname: 'Task 4' }, { id: 3, taskname: 'Task 5' }, { id: 2, taskname: 'Task 6' }, { id: 1, taskname: 'Task 7' }],
    result = array.reduce((r, o) => {
        var group = r.find(({ id }) => o.id === id);
        if (group) {
            group.taskname += ', ' + o.taskname;
        } else {
            r.push(Object.assign({}, o));
        }
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var array1 = [
  {id:1, taskname: 'Task 1'},
  {id:1, taskname: 'Task 2'},
  {id:2, taskname: 'Task 3'},
  {id:1, taskname: 'Task 4'},
  {id:3, taskname: 'Task 5'},
  {id:2, taskname: 'Task 6'},
  {id:1, taskname: 'Task 7'},
]


let byId = []

array1.forEach(item => {
    const {id, taskname} = item
    if(!byId[id-1]) {
        byId[id-1] = {id, taskname}
    } else {
        byId[id-1].taskname += ", " + taskname + " "
    }
})


console.log(byId)
```